# How to get cell data of specific row from the dynamically created HTML table?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

How to get cell data of a specific row from the dynamically created HTML table in JSP?

I am creating JSP Page in the following way

1. Connect to MySQL Databse
2. Fetch rows from table based on criteria
3. Construct HTML table dybamically based on the rows returned in **step 2**
4. The first column of table contains checkbox
5. JSP page contains a **Submit** button
6. Select checkbox for some row(s)
7. On Submit button click, How can i check which row checkbox is selected?

Comment: Consider registering your user account. This is your third account and the other two are now unusable: http://stackoverflow.com/users/414161/sohail and http://stackoverflow.com/users/414169/sohail Unregistered accounts are by a cookie tied to a specific machine and webbrowser. This is not useful if you want to maintain a history of your questions or want to reuse the same account at other machines/webbrowsers.

Answer (score 2):

Give all checkboxes the same name, but a different value, e.g. the row ID.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="row">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="rowid" value="${row.id}"></td>
            <td>${row.name}</td>
            <td>${row.value}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Then you can obtain the checked ones in the server side using [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) as follows:

```
String[] rowids = request.getParameterValues("rowid");
// ...
```