# How to get cell value from selected row in HTML table?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

Having a table like...

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%" id="mytab1">
<tr id="A1">
    <td>100</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Someplace</td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="A2">
    <td>101</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Someplace</td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to get the value of the first cell in a row, in which I've pressed the "Submit" button. I'm a newbie in this. This is an example, but I'm really working on a dynamically created html table in a jsp page, similar to this [How to get cell data of specific row from the dynamically created HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793948/how-to-get-cell-data-of-specific-row-from-the-dynamically-created-html-table) question. I just can't get it working.

Comment: Or make a form and set up html hidden fields

Comment: Could someone give a code example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of work javascript does very well.

1. Change submit to buttons with handler;
2. Put the handler into head

The resulted code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function submitter(btn) {
    var param = btn.parentElement.parentElement.id;
    var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];
    myForm.elements["param"].value = param;
    myForm.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#someurl" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="param" />
<table border="1" style="width: 100%" id="mytab1">
<tr id="A1">
    <td>100</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Someplace</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitter(this)" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="A2">
    <td>101</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Someplace</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitter(this)" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Argh! I hate the "I have no idea what I'm doing" feeling when learning something new. Thank you :3

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden field in each row and check for the submitted value..as below:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%" id="mytab1">
<tr id="A1">
    <td>100</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Someplace</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="A1" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="A2">
<td>101</td>
<td>Jane</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>Someplace</td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="A2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
```

Use the same name for all the hidden fields, so that in the controller you can fetch the submitted value